# How to search for duplicates and then highlight them in a dataframe just like excel (worksheets in that case) does?

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, highlight

I want to highlight some values into a dataframe. I need to compare 2 columns on different dataframes (df1 and df2) then highlight the values that are duplicated and show them inside the first dataframe, df1.

To give you and idea, in excel you can achive this by using a countif formula, here is a video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VhECzNIQTIY

There's any way to do this with pandas? or python in general.

Thanks!

---

Update.

Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd

#Exporting raw data from a csv file
DataOrigin = pd.read_csv('RAWDATA.csv')
#Sorting raw data per interesting columns
DataOriginSorted = DataOrigin.sort_values(['srcip','attack','dstip'])
#Exporting some columns of historical data and sorting them
Historicaldata2 = pd.read_excel('Historicaldata.xlsx', sheet_name=1, usecols = ['Source_IP','Ticket','Customer_Notification','Hostname','Service_desk_ticket'])
Historicaldata2Sorted = Historicaldata2.sort_values(['Source_IP','Ticket'])
#Creating a multindex variable with sorted raw data
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(DataOriginSorted)
Sorted_DataOrigin = pd.DataFrame(index=index)
#Making a count of events per source IP and exporting them as a csv for the code to work (rename column oepration)
Daily_IncidentsIPS = pd.crosstab(DataOrigin.srcip,DataOrigin.attack).to_csv('ControlFile1.csv')
Daily_IncidentsIPS = pd.read_csv('ControlFile1.csv').rename(columns = {'srcip': 'Source_IP'}, inplace = False )
#Mergin 2 dataframes to find coincident data and exporting them to a csv for the next operations to take place and using only interesting columns
Historical2vsSortedOrigin = Historicaldata2Sorted.merge(Daily_IncidentsIPS,left_on='Source_IP',right_on='Source_IP', how='inner').to_csv('ControlFile2.csv')
Historical2vsSortedOrigin = pd.read_csv('ControlFile2.csv', usecols = ['Ticket','Hostname','Source_IP','Customer_Notification','Service_desk_ticket'])
#Searching for duplicated data between two interesting dataframes
duplicated = Daily_IncidentsIPS['Source_IP'].isin(Historical2vsSortedOrigin['Source_IP'])
#Creating a rule to color the rows where the duplicated values are present
def row_styler(row):
    return ['background-color: yellow' if duplicated[row.name] else ''] * len(row)

#Creating a multindex variable to show the data as I want it
index2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(Historical2vsSortedOrigin)
IncidentMatching = pd.DataFrame(index=index2)
#Saving 3 interesting dataframes in an excel file, highlighting the results of previous "search for duplicated" operation
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:\\Users\myuser\Documents\Spyder\Results_IPS.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
Daily_IncidentsIPS.style.apply(row_styler, axis=1).to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
Sorted_DataOrigin.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet2')
IncidentMatching.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet3')
writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the styling system in Pandas:

```
# Some mock data
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['David', 'Sue', 'Mary'],
    'Location': ['San Francisco', 'New York', 'Boston']
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['Sue', 'Mary', 'Joe', 'Jack']
})

# Now determine what Name is duplicated across the frames
duplicated = df1['Name'].isin(df2['Name'])
```

The next step depends on what you want to highlight. If you want to highlight only the duplicate value (like in Excel):

```
def col_styler(col):
    if col.name != 'Name':
        return [''] * len(col)

    return duplicated.map({
        True: 'background-color: yellow',
        False: ''
    })

df1.style.apply(col_styler)
```

Output:

[image]

If you want to highlight the entire row:

```
def row_styler(row):
    return ['background-color: yellow' if duplicated[row.name] else ''] * len(row)

df1.style.apply(row_styler, axis=1)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
The code doesn't output any errors but something is happening.
First of all I don't know why, but something is not working when I try to apply some functions to my dataframes, for example: I have Df1 and I want to rename a column, but I can't. I first need to export it as a csv or xlsx then import it back and only in that way I can rename the column.

Comment: Something similar is happening when I try to use the isin, a KeyError appers refering to the name of the column I'm traying to compare, but if I export the Df to a csv and, import it back, then I can use the isin without any KeyError. As I said before the code runs without errors but the color of the cells remains unchanged, I'm exporting the Df to an xlsx but I can´t see the cell background changed, the same happens if I print the Df in the console.

Comment: Update. The same issue is happenig. If I export to an xlsx file the output of the .style.apply instruction then I can see the changes. I don't know what's going on here :S the problem is that I'm adding unnecessary lines to my code. Is like if pandas isn't recognizing the original Df's as they are or something. I'm totally noob at programing so I can't realize what's wrong